# What's the purpose of declaring function within scope of another function if one cannot define it

Tags: c++, function

What's the purpose of declaring a function in the scope of another function if one cannot define it?

For example:

```
int f(int a)
{
    return a;
}
void g()
{
    void f(char c);
}
```

I can declare `void f(char c);` within scope `g()`  but cannot define it. Therefore this declaration dies with the scope of `g()`. What's the purpose of declaring functions in the manner when it seems to be of no use?

Comment: It's just a normal function protorype, just at non-namespace scope. It may be used to interact with a function defined in an other file or in the same file, but below.

Comment: In general, there is no purpose in doing that. The C++ grammar allows it, but that doesn't mean you should be doing it.

Comment: It is scoped to that function.

Comment: @NeilButterworth But why allow this? In his book, Bjarne Stroustrup has dedicated a whole section to it. I guess it must be of some importance.

Comment: The big thing about declarations is to tell the *compiler* (and almost more importantly the readers of the code) that something exists *somewhere*. Exactly *where* doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: @Raindrop Functions don't create a named scope for declarations like this, so while you would not be able to access the f() function from elsewhere (that did not also declare the function), you are not declaring a function called g::f.

Comment: If you want to use function defined elsewhere, in a different translation unit for example, you can "import" it like this

Comment: You might also want to read more about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) to understand why *forward declarations* like that might be useful.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: So it is inaccessible? Then what is the point in language standards to allow such declaration?

Comment: @Raindrop If the function is declared within the another function, and nowhere else, it is only accessible inside that function. But anything that wants to can also declare that function, so you have no protection or namespacing, and generally you want to declare the function in a header file. Declaring functions at function scope is not idiomatic C or C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I agree but I only wonder why they allow such declaration? Could you show a useful usage of it? Thank you.

Comment: @Raindrop As I said in my first comment, I don't believe it is useful.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I agree with you now. I think he just introduced this because it's a possibility. Thanks.

Comment: @Lashit - The language syntax just says *declaration*, nowhere does it say *only useful declaration*. Partly because nobody cared to make a list of *exactly* what is useful and what is not.

Comment: @BoPersson I can agree it's a bit useless feature but I was just curious as Stroustrup mentioned it in his book multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it allows g to call the function, I've renamed it to h for clarity:

```
int f(int a)
{
    return a;
}
void g()
{
    void h(int c);
    h( 100 );
}

void h(int c)
{
}

int main()
{
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

but doesn't declare the function to be available to others, this wont compile:

```
int f(int a)
{
    return a;
}
void g()
{
    void h(int c);
    h( 100 );
}

void i()
{
    h(10);
}

void h(int c)
{
}

int main()
{
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of this scenario.